# How to hide vertical scrollpane but use its function?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a simple Java swing application.
In my JPanel, I have a simple JScrollPane but I don't want to show the vertical scrollbar. So, I have build this code:

```
jScrollPaneRicetta = new JScrollPane();
jScrollPaneRicetta.setViewportView(vp);
jScrollPaneRicetta.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
jScrollPaneRicetta.setPreferredSize(dTabellaRicetta);
```

Now with this code, I don't show the vertical scrollpane, but if the table have more row, I can't scroll the table to show the last row.
Now, my question is, how can I hide the vertical scrollpane but use its function?

Comment: it's kind of confusing, you want to scroll to a vertain view but don't want to use the scroller?!

Comment: Yes I want use the scroller but I don't want to show it

Comment: Isn't it about time you start to `accept` answers from your previous questions before you start asking new questions? You continue to ask questions daily but fail to take the time to accept an answer when you get help.  `how can I hide the vertical scrollpane but use its function?` - how do you expect to use this function? Is it just magically going to scroll on its own? What does the user do the get the data to scroll. You will get a better answer when you ask a better question will the complete requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the viewport

```
int x,y;//wherever you want to set
jScrollPaneRicetta.getViewportView().setViewPosition(new Point(x,y));
```

Comment: see at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JViewport.html#setViewPosition%28java.awt.Point%29 : "Sets the view coordinates that appear in the upper left hand corner of the viewport, does nothing if there's no view."

Comment: if it's not working you have either no view or you use the wrong coordinates.... if you think you have the right coordinates and a valid view then you describe a problem that's not mentioned in your uestion

Comment: @bircastri, yes this code will work. If you think it doesn't then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates how you implemented the suggestion.